# Does a basic sql AG require participant sql servers to be in the same windows cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16

I'm using sql standard edition which supports the basic availability groups (1 db per AG).

I have gone through above documentation and there is no mention of windows cluster.

My understanding is that since it supports automatic failover it should need a windows cluster. Please can someone confirm for me and point me to documentation.

Note- documentation has quote as follows:

> It is created and managed much like traditional (advanced) Always On
> Availability Groups (SQL Server) with Enterprise Edition.

The normal (advanced/enterprise) AG are of 2 types -

1. HA (this requires cluster);
2. Non-HA [Readonly/no auto failover] (this doesn't require cluster).

Therefore I'm looking for documentation about this to get clarity whether basic AG needs cluster for auto-failover, and whether no cluster is needed for manual failover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emphasis mine, from the docs page you linked to:

> It is created and managed much like traditional (advanced) Always On Availability Groups (SQL Server) with Enterprise Edition. **The differences and limitations of basic availability groups are summarized in this document.**

Since normal ("Advanced") Availability Groups require all the servers to be part of the same Windows Cluster, and nothing different is called out, it's safe to say that Basic Availability Groups also require the servers to be in the same Windows Cluster.

Also from the same page:

> - No read access on secondary replica.

So there would be no point in setting up a read-scale (clusterless) AG on Standard Edition.

Comment: The normal AG are of 2 types - 1. HA (this requires cluster); 2. Non-HA[Readonly/no auto failover] (this doesn't require cluster). Therefore I'm looking for documentation about this to get clarity whether basic AG needs cluster when we need auto failover, and whether no cluster is needed for manual failover.

Comment: @variable There's only one type of AOAG though - HA (requiring a cluster), which is what Josh referenced from the docs in his answer: "*It is created and managed much like traditional (advanced) **Always On** Availability Groups*"